# What is the difference between key exchange protocol and key distribution protocol?

Tags: encryption, public-key, keys, key-exchange

Can someone please explain what exactly is the difference between key exchange protocol and key distribution protocol? I looked on the Internet but it was not clear to me. I would be grateful if somebody could either explain it or direct me to some references.

Answer (score 0):

My very untechnical analogy would be, it's the difference between making sure the right people get the right invitations to the party and how you go about getting the invitations to them.